# Read CLR Performance Counter of IIS w3WP Asp MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, performancecounter

I want to read the %Time in GC Performance counter from a ASP.NET MVC Site which runs inside iis (so in the w3wp process)

When I look in the PerformanceMonitor I can see that there is a w3wp related to this counter
[image]

They are also reporing correct values.

For reading the counters i 've the following code:

```
var myCounter = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory", "% Time in GC", "w3wp"); 
var raw = myCounter.RawValue;
```

But I got this exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance 'w3wp' does not exist in
>   the specified Category.

I also resolved the instance name like described in the process here its also w3wp and w3wp#1

When I iterate over the categories in which the w3wp belongs to i can see that there are only 2 categories
**Process** and **Thread**.

Comment: This must be run as administrator btw

Comment: Yes i did. just not mentioned in the post

Comment: @BoasEnkler did you ever get an answer to this? I have just run in to the same issue